# how can i support jquery with iis 6 in windows server 2003

Tags: javascript, jquery, iis

I used jquery coding for some kind of image scrolling and styles to menu bars in my master page when I executed on IIS it is not working and giving the below alert messages jquery and java script I used for Scrolling images with different styles using CSS styles and I downloaded and kept nivo slider pack.js in my projects folder

IIS 6 is giving the following alert message:

> an error occurred in the script on this page

and asking whether you want to continue scripts on this page?

Comment: please help anyone knows ...abt iis 6 and jquery settings...

Comment: [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) is a web server and typically just reads and serves `jquery.js` as a static file. Do you happen to mean [IE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer)? If so, what version of jQuery are you trying to use? Not all versions of jQuery [support IE 6](http://jquery.com/browser-support/).

Comment: you really need to learn a lot before posting this question. What was the error in the debuggers, what line, what code was it referring to etc etc.